# How to force timer throttling for the active tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome (and other web browsers) implements a timer throttling mechanism to reduce CPU usage of non-focused (background) tabs and thus extend the laptop's battery life: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs#budget-based_background_timer_throttling

Is it possible to force-enable this throttling for the active (foreground, focused) tab as well?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc macOS El capitan, but why does it matter?